# Expose Vagrant Virtualenv Dependencies to Host

Tags: ide, vagrant, virtualbox, virtualenv

I am using virtualbox+vagrant+virtualenv to virtualize my python development stack.

A given project will have its own virtualenv, including dependency libraries.

How can I expose these guest dependency files to the host? I am looking to configure my eclipse IDE to be able to traverse 3rd party code imports.

Thanks!

Comment: Using a shared folder does not work here, as the files belong to the Vagrant Guest

Comment: I think that Pycharm and it's remote environment feature will suit better for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Am in the same exact situation and been searching for ways to have Eclipse mount a python path located in a virtual environment in a vagrant virtual machine. Its been three days now and am almost giving up on Eclipse and thinking of using Atom or Sublime text and using terminal for debugging. If you get a solution. Don't forget to post it here.